# Delete the repeated Item inside a List of object C#

Tags: c#, linq

I want to compare the element of a list of object ,delete the repeated Item and increment the number of the quantity of that Item (C# code ), I don't know if I should use LinQ,For or foreach statement : I have a list of OrderItem I want to delete the OrderItem that have the same FK_ArtikelId and increment the Qantity of the OrderItem . Exp:

```
for (int i=1 ; i < lot.Count   ; i ++)
{
    for (j = i + 1; j <= lot.Count; j++)
    {
        if (lot[i].FK_ArticleId.Equals(lot[j].FK_ArticleId))
        {
            lot[i].Quantity += lot[j].Quantity;
            lot.Remove(lot[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `OrderItem` class?

Comment: Truth is that if you use tools such as ReSharper etc. it often suggests changing foreach loop into corresponding LINQ expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the GroupBy linq method and process the resulting groups: given the class

```
public class Article
{
    public int FK_ArticleId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

and the following list:

```
var list = new List<Article>()
{
    new Article() {FK_ArticleId = 1, Quantity = 10}
    , new Article() {FK_ArticleId = 1, Quantity = 10}
    , new Article() {FK_ArticleId = 1, Quantity = 10}
    , new Article() {FK_ArticleId = 2, Quantity = 100}
    , new Article() {FK_ArticleId = 2, Quantity = 100}
    , new Article() {FK_ArticleId = 3, Quantity = 1000}
};
```

The following linq query returns what you need:

```
list.GroupBy(a => a.FK_ArticleId)
    .Select(g => new Article() {FK_ArticleId = g.Key, Quantity = g.Sum(a => a.Quantity)});

// article id 1, quantity 30
// article id 2, quantity 200
// article id 3, quantity 1000
```

If you don't want to create a new article, you can take the first of the resulting group and set its `Quantity` to the correct value:

```
var results = list.GroupBy(a => a.FK_ArticleId)
    .Select(g =>
    {
        var firstArticleOfGroup = g.First();
        firstArticleOfGroup.Quantity = g.Sum(a => a.Quantity);
        return firstArticleOfGroup;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @DavidG. Was it the horizontal rule that did the trick?

Comment: I think you need to sum the quantities, not count the articles.

Comment: Thanks alot for the linq solution ill try to implement it and adapt it to my case but for the Moment i have tried this solution , it works but i heard that it has slow down the app , is that true ??

Comment: //Sorting
            var list = swing
                .OrderBy(i => i.FK_ArticleId)
                .ToList();

           //Remove the duplicated OrderItems
            Int32 index = 0;
            while (index < list.Count - 1)
            {
                if (list[index].FK_ArticleId == list[index + 1].FK_ArticleId)
                {
                    list[index + 1].Quantity += list[index].Quantity;
                    list.RemoveAt(index);
                 
                }
                else

                    index++;
            }

Comment: Comments are not really suited to add some code. You should instead ask another question regarding the timing questions you may have. I would advise against though, the best thing to do is to measure your code execution: there are so many factors at play in a program that you cannot really guess

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test but this should give you an idea of the power of linq...

```
 var stuff  = lot
  .GroupBy(p => p.FK_ArticleId)
  .Select(g => g)
  .ToList();
```

This should give you groups of articleIDs whereby you can easily get counts, create new consolidated lists etc.

Comment: That will return a list of `IGrouping<OrderItem>` not a list of `OrderItem`. Furthermore, there is no aggregation of `Quantity` property.

Comment: Thanks Pierre grouping is not my strong suit, but I knew it would be in the answer for the op.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you can't use `foreach` because you're modifying the list and the `Enumerator` will throw an exception. You can do the following with Linq:

```
var grouped = lot.GroupBy(x => x.FK_ArticleId).ToArray();
foreach(var group in grouped)
{
    group.First().Quantity = group.Sum(item => item.Quantity);
}
```

Now, first item in each group will contain the sum of all the quantities of items with the same `FK_ArticleId`. Now, to get the results use this:

```
var results = grouped.Select(g => g.First());
```

At this point it's purely your decision whether to return the results as a separate collection or insert them into the original list. If you opt for the second approach, don't forget to clear the list first:

```
list.Clear();
list.AddRange(results);
```

**EDIT**

A more elegant solution to accumulating the `Quantity` property into the first item of each group would be the following:

```
data.GroupBy(x=>x.FK_ArticleId)
    .Select(g => g.Aggregate((acc, item) => 
        {
             acc.Quantity = item.Quantity; 
             return acc;
        }));
```

This is what I scrapped in LinqPad:

[image: Results.]